# How to get the selected element in jQuery event delegation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to understand jQuery delegation by writing a short script, but I encountered 2 problems.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="text" />
    <div id="msg"></div>

    <script>
        function showMsg() {
            if ($("#text").val() === "") {
                $("#msg").html("Your input is empty");
            } else {
                $("#msg").html("You have entered something")
            }
        }

        $("#text").on("blur", showMsg());
    </script>
</body>
```

1). This event delegation doesn't work as expected, the message `"Your input is empty"` always shows itself indefinitely. How to fix this?

2). In the `showMsg()` function I have to explicitly use `$("#text")` for the script to work, if I use `$(this)` it won't work. What if I have a lot of input fields that need to use this function, is it possible to uniformly define the function so that those input fields can use it without having to change anything in the function?

Comment: 1) There's no event delegation. 2) You're not even binding a handler. You're invoking a function right away. Drop the `()` after `showMsg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is change

```
 $("#text").on("blur", showMsg());
```

to

```
 $("#text").on("blur", showMsg);
```

This will also fix your `$(this)` problem. You can set that back now.

Comment: Thanks you but hat about question 2? Is there a way to define the function so that it can be used on multiple inputs?

Comment: When you include the brackets, the function is run immediately, and since the function returns nothing, you're essentially saying on blur do nothing. By omitting the brackets you're saying on blur run the function stored in the variable showMsg.

Comment: Oh right now I get it, the 2 problems can now be solved by just removing the brackets. Thanks a lot!